# synchronization and visibility

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```
// In Thread1  
x=5;  
synchronization(obj)  
{  
    // do something (no operations involving x)  
}

// In thread 2  
synchronization(obj)  
{  
    // do something(operations involving x)  
}
```

Is there any requirement that JVM should first execute all the statements before a synchronized block before entering that block. In Thread-1 since synchronized block doesn't have any operations to do with `x` can it first execute synchronized block and then the assignment operation `x=5`.

And what would Thread-2 see for the value of `x` in its synchronized block. Suppose Thread-1 first executes and then Thread-2 executes and both of them are running on the same object, `x = 0` when object was created.

We can say that synchronized block in Thread-1 happens before synchronized block in Thread-2. So what should be the value of `x` in Thread-2 within its synchronized block?

Answer (score 3):

*Is there any requirement that jvm should first execute all the statements before a synchronized bloc before entering that bloc*

Yes. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html says:

> Each action in a thread happens-before every action in that thread
>   that comes later in the program's order.

Given that the assignment to x *happens-before* the first synchronized block execution, and that the first synchronized block execution *happens-before* the second synchronized block execution, the value assigned to x in the first thread will be visible to the second one. (*happens-before* is transitive).

Comment: since sync bloc in Thread1 doesn't involve any operations with x, cant the jvm first execute the sync bloc and then x=5 operation since jvm does't have to execute all the operation in a sequential order

Comment: @vlk its still has to acquire the lock. even `synchronized(obj) { }` does something and can block forever if the object is locked elsewhere.

Comment: @PeterLawrey is there any possibility that compiler can reorder the instructions in Thread1 such that sync bloc executes first and then the assignment operation x=5

Comment: @PeterLawrey can we have an order like this 1)Thread1 sync bloc 2)Thread2 sync bloc 3) x=5 or 1)Thread2 sync bloc 2)Thread1 sync bloc 3) x=5

Comment: You can have t1 enter sync, t1 exit sync, t2 enter sync, x = 5, t2 exit sync. OR t2 enter sync, x = 5, t2 exit sync, t1 enter sync, t1 exit sync. Note: there is protection from the start of the block to the end, not just the line with `synchronized()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey why cant this happen 1)t1 enters sync bloc, 2)t1 exits sync bloc 3)t2 enters sync bloc 4)t2 exits sync bloc 5)t1 executes x = 5. since statements can be ordered anyway as long as it doesn't effect execution, within t1 sync bloc can be executed first and then x=5.

Comment: @vjk, I am sorry, I miss placed the `x = 5` in my mind. I thought it was the operation in t2.  If x=5, it must occur before t1 enters the synchronized block. but it can occur before, during or after whatever t2 does.

Answer (score 0):

In Thread-2, `x` could be a few things:

- 0, if Thread-2's synchronized block ran before `x = 5` (it could also have actually ran after it, but have a previously cached value of 0 which it's not obligated to update, since there's no happens-before edge between `x = 5` and Thread-2)
- 5, if Thread-2's synchronized block ran after `x = 5` (and happened to have had its value flushed) but before Thread-1's `synchronized` block
- whatever value Thread-1's `synchronized` block assigns to `x` (which in your case doesn't happen, so this option is out)
- some other value altogether, if `x` is a `long` or `double`, since the words within those types don't have to be atomically updated. (see [jls 17.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/memory.html#17.7)). Note that in this specific case, that "other value altogether" would be 0 or 5 (if you only saw the top or bottom halves of the `long`, respectively). But if you had a value with non-0 values for both words, you could see any combination of those words' potential values.

In Thread-1, as JB Nizet points out, within-thread semantics mean that you won't see `x` as an uninitialized 0 -- it'll either be 5 or whatever Thread-2 sets it to (which of course could be 0).

Comment: can the compiler reorder the instruction in thread1 such that sync bloc executes first and then x=5 operation.

Comment: @vjk As others have written, no. Within any one thread, things have to run in the order you wrote them (well not actually, but they have to run in an order such that you can't tell the difference). But you could definitely have an order (either actually or apparent, because of memory caching) of 1) `x = 5`, 2) Thread-2's synch block, 3) Thread-1's synch block.

Comment: can we have an order like this 1) thread2 sync block, 2)thread1 sync block 3) x=5 or 1)thread1 sync bloc, 2)thread2 sync bloc, 3)x=5

Comment: @vjk When you talk about order, you have to specify who sees it. For instance, thread 1 could not see such an order, but thread 2 could.

Comment: from within thread1 can we have this sequence 1)Thread1 sync bloc 2) x=5.

Comment: @vjk No. Again, within a thread, actions have to execute such that they appear as if they executed in the order they appear in the code. Since the code specifies `x=5` before the sync block, within thread-1, `x=5` has to be executed before the sync block (or at least such that you can't tell the difference). The simple answer is, no, you can't view that sequence from within thread 1.

Comment: in the sync bloc in thread1 since i am not doing any operations on x, how would it matter if sync bloc is executed first and then x=5(both of them are the same first x=5 then sync bloc or first sync bloc and then x=5)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10858/discussion-between-yshavit-and-vjk)

Answer (score 0):

1. All statements in a single thread are executed sequentially.
2. What you describe in your second question is a race condition. Thread #1 is assigning the a value to x outside of a synchronized block. Depending on the order of execution Thread #2 could see x = 0 or x = 5;
3. For your third assumption, x would equal 5.

Comment: i saw in java specs that compiler can reorder the instructions when it doesn't effect the execution of that thread in isolation, so there is no requirement that all the statements should be executed sequentially

Comment: I believe what you are referring to are compiler/jvm optimizations. I think JB Nizet answered it well with the provided link. For all intent and purposes x=5 happens before the sync block.

Answer (score 0):

How do you make sure the change on `x` is visible to `Thread 2`?

`x` is not in `Thread 1` sync block and I think you didn't make it `volatile`, so even `x` assignment happens before `Thread 2`, `Thread 2` may still read the stale value of `x`.